# laravel upload csv and import csv file data to database with integer field

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-excel

I am trying to upload csv and import csv data to database it works fine, 
but I am facing issue with the integer field in the database.

My csv file have **product name** and **quantity** field

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($uploaded_file)->chunk(100, function($results) {
    foreach($results as $result) {
        echo $result->quantity;     # When I try to insert it is 0 because it is string
        # I tried typecasting (int)$result->quantity; it leads to 0
        # And also intval($result->quantity); this too leads to 0
    }
});
```

[This is the package I am using](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import)

Comment: Can you insert 0 directly into your database table?

Answer (score 1):

$xls_datas = Excel::load($xlsFile, function($reader) {
                    })->toArray();

```
//$csv_values = $this->readCSV($csvFile);           
//$except_first_row_excel = array_slice($csv_values, 1, -1);
//$total_excel_rows = $except_first_row_excel-1;

if(count($xls_datas) > 0)
{
    foreach($xls_datas as $xls_data)
    {
      $xls_data->quantity;//insert query
    }
}
```